# Error creating procedure: declare and end error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm starting with the procedures and I'm lost with these problems.

I do not understand why I get an error when I add the procedure because I think it's ok and neither does it cause an error in the end.

I attach the code.

Errors:

> LINE/COL ERROR
>
> ---
>
> 10/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"
>   16/4     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with    << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_MOVIMIENTOS (
INSERTMOV_COD_BANCO  IN NUMBER,
INSERTMOV_COD_SUCUR  IN NUMBER,
INSERTMOV_NUM_CTA    IN NUMBER,
INSERTMOV_FECHA_MOV  IN DATE,
INSERTMOV_TIPO_MOV   IN CHAR,
INSERTMOV_IMPORTE    IN NUMBER
);

DECLARE
    sql_str VARCHAR2(500):='';

BEGIN
    sql_str:=sql_str||'INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTOS (';
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
END;    
/
```

Comment: problem with `;` before `DECLARE`. Check https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php

Comment: The `;` is only one problem here. The other one is that `DECLARE` starts an anonymous block. An anonymous block cannot appear within the declaration section of another block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample syntax:

```
create or replace procedure insert_movimientos
    ( insertmov_cod_banco in number
    , insertmov_cod_sucur in number
    , insertmov_num_cta   in number
    , insertmov_fecha_mov in date
    , insertmov_tipo_mov  in varchar2
    , insertmov_importe   in number )
is
    sql_str varchar2(500) := 'INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTOS (';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
end;
/
```

The trailing slash is for the client application so may not be required depending on what tool you are using.

I changed the datatype for `insertmov_tipo_mov`. `char` adds blank spaces which nobody needs, and is provided mainly for ANSI compatibility. It's best to use the standard type.

Even better, use `table name.columnname%type` to anchor it to the type of the corresponding table column.

A lot of examples online are in uppercase, for no clear reason. You don't as a rule write computer code in uppercase.

Comment: how to execute this procedure i dont know, sorry I'm starting

Comment: i am trying with EXEC INSERT_MOVIMIENTOS (0, 0, 0, '2008-11-11', 'o', 0);
and answer with "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at line 1"

Comment: The 4th parameter needs to be a date literal or variable, not `'2008-11-11'`. Have a look at the documentation for [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ).

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra `;`, or write `IS`

Syntax of create procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_MOVIMIENTOS (
    ...
)
IS
    sql_str VARCHAR2(500):='';
    ...
;
```

Comment: There's no `declare` unless you need a sub-block, in which case it would need to go after the first `begin`.